# How To fill all the recipients /Signer and move the workflow to the second signer through API/Rest Web Service

Tags: docusignapi

I have a docusign template created with below signing order(1.Employee 2.Manager).[Ref below screen]

I am able to fill the form element and the send the draft envelope to the  first signer i.e Employee through API using the POSTMAN.()

## Problem Statement:-

1.As of now I have hard coded the manager name and email Id in Template but actually I wanted to fill this dynamically while creating the Envelope.

2.When I am sending the Envelope with the data from postman, It is creating a draft Envelope for the first signer i.e for employee but my requirement is that the first signer task (Entering the data and move the workflow to Manager ) should be perform from API.

Thanks For helping Us.

[image]

Comment: Answered below! If it helps, be sure to like and upvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your draft envelope by making an additional RESTful request:

```
PUT /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes/{{envelope_id}}
```

If you want to fill in the fields of your employee recipient, just specify something like this in your request body:

```
{
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "name": "InsertDynamicNameHere",
                "email": "emailGoesHere",
                "recipientId": "2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew Roknich ,On my second question ,Is it possible to  Finish/Complete  the Employee Task from API and move the workflow to the Second signer.something like {

 "status": "completed"
}